# Sum of array in one cell produces different result from sum of the array elements

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I want to do a simple calculation (say, addition) on a set of values on the basis of some keys, as in:

```
         Col A       Col B           Col C            Col D          Col E
Row 1  **Key**     **Value**     **Key Input**     **VLOOKUP**     **Array**
Row 2     x            10              x               10             10 
Row 3     y            20                               0              0
Row 4     z            30              y               20             20
```

Columns D and E contain the values for the key inputs in Column C:

Column D uses VLOOKUP: `D2` = `IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(C2, $A$2:$B$4, 2)), VLOOKUP(C2, $A$2:$B$4, 2), 0)`

Column E uses an ARRAY: `E2:E4` = `{=IF(ISTEXT(C2:C4), INDEX($B$2:$B$4, MATCH(C2:C4, $A$2:$A$4, 0))}`

I want to sum the values of the inputs x, y in Column C.

Summing D2:D4 or E2:E4 produces the correct result for summing the values of x and y: 30

Summing the elements of the ARRAY in E directly produces a different (incorrect) result:

`{=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(C2:C4), INDEX($B$2:$B$4, MATCH(C2:C4, $A$2:$A$4, 0)),0))}` or
`{=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(C2:C4), INDEX($B$2:$B$4, MATCH(C2:C4, $A$2:$A$4, 0))))}` produce the value 20.

I have tried this in a number of different ways (conditioning with ISTEXT, using MATCH, etc.) and the behavior is always the same. Would anybody have a suggestion as to why this happens and how it can be corrected? The option to construct the array first (as in E above) and then sum it is neither attractive nor feasible because the operation has to be repeated multiple times.

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & Share some sample data the Screen Shot will help us to understand the real data and the formula you have used so far,, help us to fix it !!

Comment: Use the SUMPRODUCT,,, formula like this ,,, `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$5=$D3)*($B$3:$B$5))` & fill down you get `10` and `20` !